# Problem with converting datetime to Oracle's format in WebApi's query - 'error has occurred' message

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, asp.net-web-api

From webApi2 project I'm adding rows to Oracle Db. When testing this method on my development machine, everything goes well and new record is created. Having deployed it to server and tested there, I noticed that no record is added and I'm getting back message saying "An error has occurred"..

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateTpmEntry")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Process))]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateTpmEntry(Process p)
    {
        string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var Con = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConStr);

        if (Con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            Con.Open();
        }


        string iStr = @"INSERT INTO ifc.qmes_tpm_repairs_imp (order_nr, manager_nr, start_date, closemean_nr, end_date, initial_diagnosis, repair_actions, STATUS) 
                        VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', TO_DATE('{2}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = POLISH'), '{3}', TO_DATE('{4}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = POLISH'), '{5}', '{6}' ,'{7}')";

        iStr = string.Format(iStr, p.Number, p.Manager, p.StartDate, p.FinishedBy, p.EndDate, p.InitialDiagnosis, p.RepairActions, p.Status);

        var Command = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(iStr, Con);

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return Ok();

    }
```

I tested it more and found out that everything goes well when I'm taking end_date and start_date out from iStr, so the problem must be related to date format. I thought that TO_DATE function takes care for the date to be in appropriate format, but apparently it's not enough. Here's exemplary iStr:

```
    INSERT INTO ifc.qmes_tpm_repairs_imp (order_nr, manager_nr, start_date, closemean_nr, end_date, initial_diagnosis, repair_actions, STATUS) 
VALUES ('A/2018/152170', 'MSMITH', TO_DATE('2018-10-08 14:48:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = POLISH'), 'MSMITH', TO_DATE('2018-10-08 14:54:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = POLISH'), 'Machine not working', 'Call service for control panel' ,'AC')
```

I checked NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS tables both on development machine and on deploy machine but all settings look identical..

Comment: Rule number 1. Use sql parameters!.

Comment: @Reniuz Can't believe it, works like a charm now! I hadn't been able to get them to work (adding paremeters works a bit differently comparing to Sql Server) so I coded it directly, but instant karma got me. Thanks! I wouldn't have guessed it myself!

Comment: Nice. But remember there is rule number 2 - ALWAYS use sql parameters :)